# Entity Framework Code First Automatic Migrations to Azure Database

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 5.0 Code First and am testing automatic migrations.  Everything works fine when I'm working locally but when I upload the database to Azure and change the connection string accordingly the migration fails to work.  I'm using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer.  Is this something that Azure doesn't allow?  I'm not getting any error.  Just no migration.  Ideas?

Comment: I use migrations on azure and have never had any issues, is there any kind of error message?

Comment: No message.  Azure databases don't have system tables so you can't add dbo._MigrationHistory.  I thought that might be the problem.  Are you doing automatic migrations?  Are you using Entity Framework Code First?  Are you doing them in code?  What is you process?

Comment: im using git deploy and i didnt have to do anything special at all with the database, it just worked first try. Yes im using EF 5, code first and auto migrations

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something on the website that would trigger a call to DB.

I had this problem, until I realized that the migrations weren't run until you did something on the website that triggered a call to DB -- e.g. attempt to log in. My migrations were run only then.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what happens, the migration is called the first time you access your DB context. It should be triggered during deployment or on application_start to avoid delays post migration for the first user who access the Azure website